# Correctly structuring abstraction between models and interfaces

Tags: c#

I'm not sure about the title of the question, so please excuse if it is incorrect or misleading.

I'm trying to extend the abstraction architecture between the models and the interfaces implemented on them. I'l start off by demonstrating a simple example, then I'll move to something which requires some assistance.

Ok, so I have a person interface with it's corresponding class model:

```
public interface IPersonModel<T>
    where T : ICompany
{
    T Company { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel : IPersonModel<Company>
{
    public CompanyModel Company { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyModel : ICompany
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So the above code works great, if the model class only has one property which is a complex type. Thus is can easily be used in Manager method:

```
public interface IPersonManager
{
    Task<IEnumerable<IPersonModel<CompanyModel>>> GetPersonData();
}
```

Which brings me to my actual issue. Let's say the model classes are more complex, like:

```
public interface IPersonModel<T, T2, T3>
    where T : ICompany
    where T2 : IDog<BreedModel>
    where T3 : ICar
{
    T Company { get; set; }
    T2 Dog { get; set; }
    T3 Car { get; set; }
}
```

This will result in updating the `PersonModel` class:

```
public class PersonModel : IPersonModel<Company, Dog, Car>
{
    public CompanyModel Company { get; set; }
    public DogModel Dog { get; set; }
    public CarModel Car { get; set; }
}
```

And let's not forget about the `Dog` model class:

```
public class DogModel : IDog<BreedModel>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BreedModel Breed { get; set; }
}

public class BreedModel : IBreed
{
    public string Attributes { get; set; }

    public void GetBreedData()
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Which will result in the manager method being consumed like:

```
public interface IPersonManager
{
    Task<IEnumerable<IPersonModel<CompanyModel, DogModel, CarModel>>> GetPersonData();
}
```

I would like to know whether there is a better way of doing this. If there are nested complex type properties in the models, it could turn into a very tedious exercise. If the model has 4 or 5 or even 10 complex type properties, it would turn into quite large generic implementations.

Thanks in advance!

Reason for all this trouble, in a nutshell, trying to accomplish the following architecture:

[image]

Comment: Do you really need generics at all, or could _every_ conceivable implementation of `IPersonModel` just use `ICompany`, `IDog` and `ICar` without needing to know which specific concrete implementation is being used?

Comment: @JamesThorpe the idea is to create an 'interface' assembly. This way, all the other relevant projects in the solution can use the interfaces declared in the assembly. Currently it's all over the show. Interfaces in the EF assembly, Managers assembly and so on

Comment: My advice would be to not complicate things. Without knowing the problem domain I think you're probably over-engineering this. Just my 2 cents. Of course, I could be wrong and your domain actually needs be it, but more often than not, it's not necessary.

Comment: @RichardBailey: That doesn't seem to relate to what James said. He is asking why you need Generics. Putting all your interfaces in an assembly is great but it strikes me that your `IPersonModel` doesn't need to have a generic type parameter for `ICompany` but could just declare the company as `ICompany`. For most use cases this is what you want. So do you really need all these generic types? Are you going to need to know that the Company is anything more than an ICompany?

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the reply. One thing to note, all the class names are just examples. Probable not the best use case, but I'm just trying to get the point across. Secondly, you have a valid point! I think I should just rethink the architecture a bit

Comment: And the downvote is due to....?

Comment: Was wondering about that ... Seems like these days all my questions get the good all -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see a generic type, I tend to try to understand them as: this is a *className* of `T`s: for instance `List<int>`as a *list* of *Foos* or `IComparable<Foo>` as an *IComparable* of *ints*, etc.

Would you consider a *Person* to be a *Person* of *Companies*, or a dog, a *dog* of *breeds*?

What I'm getting at, is that your type system seems to be unecessarily using generics here. What is wrong with simply using a nongeneric approach?

```
public interface IPersonModel
{
    ICompany Company { get; set; }
    IDog Dog { get; set; }
    ICar Car { get; set; }
}

public class DogModel: IDog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IBreed Breed { get; set; }
}

public class BreedModel : IBreed
{
    public string Attributes { get; set; }
    public void GetBreedData()
    {
       // ...
    }
}

public interface IPersonManager
{
    Task<IEnumerable<IPersonModel> GetPersonData();
}
```

And now your concrete `PersonModel` class would look like:

```
public class PersonModel : IPersonModel
{
    public ICompany Company { get; set; }
    public IDog Dog { get; set; }
    public ICar Car { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You'll get the following error, in the full implementation: 
'PersonModel' does not implement interface member 'IPersonModel.Dog'. 'PersonModel.Dog' cannot implement 'IPersonModel.Dog' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IDog'

unless, you are referring to not using a PersonModel, but rather construct a PersonModel in the manager method and returning that

Comment: @RichardBailey The concrete `PersonModel` needs to return the non generic interfaces. See edit.